# Pseudo element after heading showing icon that is dynamic

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, icons, pseudo-element, acfpro

Hi there I'm making a wordpress music site. I have a heading which is dynamic and linked to ACF on my singular template. Now that heading is an single/ album music title. My idea is that if the track has explicit/ strong language i want to put and icon (E) ::after the title and it will be controlled by ACF true/false button. How can i do that? My wordpress site is build with Oxygen Builder.

Spotify and Apple Music does exactly what i'm describing. The little (E) in a box.

Link: https://music.apple.com/us/album/lucky-you-feat-joyner-lucas/1434770366?i=1434770508

Can anyone help me with the code or solution?

Comment: Hi chaudes - welcome to StackOverflow. We are going to need you to provide your code so we can best determine how to implement your request. How are your music titles implemented in the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a template for showing headings then you can put a class on heading tag on the basis of radio custom field then using that class you can define CSS in your custom CSS file.
Please explain more how you are working.

Comment: Well the template is for the singular "template" for all discorgraphy posts that are made with CPT UI and ACF. The heading is a oxygen builders element. But can't seem to figure out how to make the pseudo-element in this case icon to be triggered with ACF true/false button and conditions options in Oxygen. :)